# Google Multidevice Login

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, google-oauth

we are creating web (single page app - NG app), Android and iOs app (both with phonegap) and we want to authorize user for Adwords API with offline access with Google OAUTH. We noticed that if we use iOS id and secret that refresh token that we got is not valid for web application and vice-versa. How we can resolve this? Do we need to store for every user id, pass and token in DB and then query every time with that credentials or there is some other way?

Thank you

Best,
Antonio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding login with Google, if we want to work we need to store combination for secret, emailId, refresh token for every device we want to connect.